# Finding the svg image center

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

Am a new in svg .I want to find out the svg image center programically,also display a 'dots' in center point.

Here i created a simple svg.How to shows dots in the center point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M75 0 L56 105 L225 200 Z" />

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"/> ?

Comment: @ defghi1977-not a circle, i want to find center point of different shapes of svg images.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to do...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var svg   = document.querySelector("svg");
  var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

  // get the center
  var el = document.querySelector("path");
  var bbox = el.getBBox();
  var center = {
     x: bbox.x + bbox.width/2,
     y: bbox.y + bbox.height/2
  };
  
  // create the dot
  var dot = document.createElementNS(svgns, circle);
  dot.setAttribute("cx", center.x);
  dot.setAttribute("cy", center.y);
  dot.setAttribute("r", 10);
  svg.appendChild(dot);

</script>
```

Comment: Put the code at the end of the html document, right before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Please use `bbox.x`, `bbox.y` instead of `bbox.left`, `bbox.top`.